# What code changes (code attached) required to ensure core data @FetchRequest variable behaves dynamically?

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

How should my code be modified to ensure that when an exception happens at the Core Data layer when adding a new item, that SwiftUI does NOT continue to show a new item?

Background:  When I run the below code I get an exception when adding a new item doing the "context.save()", HOWEVER whilst the new item request really failed (did not save to Core Data), the UI does show a new item.   It is as if the "lists" variable in the @FetchRequest line is not behaving dynamically.

Question - How do I fix code so that the application works properly?

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @Environment(\.managedObjectContext) var context
    @FetchRequest(fetchRequest: List.allListFetchRequest()) var lists: FetchedResults<List>

    private func addListItem() {
        let newList = List(context: context)
        newList.id = 1
        newList.title = "Testing 123"
        do {
            try context.save()
        } catch let e as NSError {
            print("Could not save new List. \(e.debugDescription)")
            return
        }

    }

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                ForEach(lists) { list in
                    Text("List = \(list.title)")
                }
            }
            .navigationBarTitle( Text("My Todo Lists") )
            .navigationBarItems(
                trailing: Button(action: {self.addListItem()} ) {
                    Image(systemName: "plus.square")
                }
            )
        }
    }
}
```

Example Output:

```
Could not save new List. Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=133021 "(null)" UserInfo={NSExceptionOmitCallstacks=true, conflictList=(
    "NSConstraintConflict (0x600001fcccc0) for constraint (\n    id\n): database: (null), conflictedObjects: (\n    \"0x600000a7e360 <x-coredata:///List/t2F01130C-0D2A-4E88-A77D-A7BA0E921C213>\",\n    \"0xfb1bb528bb57810c <x-coredata://41B391F1-A95C-4971-9584-A2D3DFFF5380/List/p3>\"\n)"
)}
```

Comment: Yes, to emulate a failure scenario

Comment: If a new item can't/doesn't get added then I don't want the UI to indicate to the user it did

Comment: Could you try to `fetch` manually in the `catch` block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jim Dovey gave me the way forward with this suggestion:

```
private func addListItem() {  
    context.performBlock { context in  
        let newList = List(context: context)  
        newList.id = 1  
        newList.title = "Testing 123"  
        do {  
            try context.save()  
        }  
        catch {  
            print("Failed to save new item. Error = \(error)")  
            context.delete(newList)  
            // don't need to save here, because we're in `performBlock` and have reverted the only unsaved change.  
        }  
    }  
}
```